# Как сделать inline block по центру (горизонтали)

Tags: html, css

Сейчас вот так

```css
    .title {
    
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

.title p {
font-size: 28px;
}

.title h1 {
font-size: 32px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
    <div class="title">
        <p>Get a video instruction</p>
        <h1>How to earn your first million</h1>     
    </div>
```

А хочу чтобы было вот так (текст в красном диве)
[image: вот так хочу]

Пробовал разные советы из интернета по выравниваню - не помогает (удивите что же мне на этот раз поможет)

Comment: `width: 100%;`.

Comment: @Grundy мне нужно чтобы `inline-block` был по центру и занимал только место для текста

Comment: @nevazno_html_css_js_1, мы можем обвернуть в еще один блок с 100% шириной?

Comment: @OliverPatterson нет нужно чтобы было так как на картинке (текст в красном диве)

Comment: `inline-block` как и просто `inline` управляется контейнером.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выровнять inline-block, применяя стили только к нему, нельзя. Единственный вариант - задать выравнивание в родительском блоке.

```css
.title {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.title p {
  font-size: 28px;
}

.title h1 {
  font-size: 32px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.container{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
    <p>Get a video instruction</p>
    <h1>How to earn your first million</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант.. Мы можем задать для `body` `display: flex` и `flex-direction: column`, тогда для `.title` сработает `margin` со значением `auto`. Не уверен, что это хороший вариант и он ничего не сломает. Но можно попробовать хотя бы.

```css
.title {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

body 
{ 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.title p {
  font-size: 28px;
}

.title h1 {
  font-size: 32px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
        <p>Get a video instruction</p>
        <h1>How to earn your first million</h1>     
</div>
```

Comment: фактически установив `flex` контейнеру у детей устанавливается `block`

Comment: да - а блок это то что занимаетс всю строку и выталкивает другие элементы а мне нужно просто чтобы было посредине

Comment: Хотя сам вопрос не очень логичен т.к смысла от того что он будет `inline:block` нету т.к этот элемент единственный в контейнере (кроме title1 нету чего-то другого)

Comment: @nevazno_html_css_js_1, нужно больше контекста. Я лично немного тогда не понимаю, чего вы хотите добится. Какой там контент еще может быть.

Comment: @nevazno_html_css_js_1, нет, `block` - это не то что ты думаешь. И в случае `flex` - `block` у дочерних элементов не влияет на "выталкивание"

Comment: @OliverPatterson та никакой - просто я сам плохой вопрос задал - я просто думал что так будет лучше когда будет вместо `block` будет `inline-block`